# Count missing values in timeseries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm using Python and Pandas to analyze a data series. My DF looks like this

```
                          ActivePowerkW  WindSpeedms  WindSpeedmsstd 
time                                                              
    2015-05-26 11:40:00       836.6328     8.234862        1.414558   
    2015-05-26 11:50:00       968.5992     8.761620        1.572579   
    2015-05-26 12:30:00       614.0503     7.267871        1.575504   
    2015-05-26 13:50:00       945.5604     8.709115        1.527079   
    2015-05-26 14:00:00       926.6531     8.538967        1.589221   
    2015-05-26 14:30:00       666.7984     7.590645        1.324495   
    2015-05-26 14:40:00       911.0134     8.466603        1.708189   
    2015-05-26 15:10:00      1256.1740     9.868224        1.636775   
    2015-05-26 15:30:00      1706.7070    11.225540        1.576277
```

Null values are omitted. I would like to count all null values as a percentage on a monthly basis.

I thought the easiest way would be to create a new time series

```
timeseries_comp = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[df_length], freq='10min')
```

and then align this with my df

```
dif = df.align(timeseries_comp)
```

and then just count the NAN. This doesn't work. Align error `unsupported type`.

What I'm finally after is something like the following

[image: Availability]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried reindexing? so `df.reindex(timeseries_comp)`

Comment: Thanks. reindex does exactly what I want. Now I need to count the on a monthly basis. I have tried  `Avail_Count=df.resample('M', how={df.count():'count'})` and seems to work but I'm not about the results.

Comment: You should be able to do `df.reindex(timeseries_comp).groupby([df.index.year,df.index.month]).value_counts(drop_na=False)` this should give you all unique counts including `NaN`, or maybe `df.reindex(timeseries_comp).groupby([df.index.year,df.index.month]).apply(pd.Series.isnull).sum()`

Comment: They both fail with `invalid character in identifier`. But I just want to count NAN

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'd `reindex` using your time_series, then `groupby` on your index and then apply `isnull` and call `sum`:

```
In [113]:
# load your data, you can ignore this step
t="""time,ActivePowerkW,WindSpeedms,WindSpeedmsstd
2015-05-26 11:40:00,836.6328,8.234862,1.414558
2015-05-26 11:50:00,968.5992,8.761620,1.572579
2015-05-26 12:30:00,614.0503,7.267871,1.575504
2015-05-26 13:50:00,945.5604,8.709115,1.527079
2015-05-26 14:00:00,926.6531,8.538967,1.589221
2015-05-26 14:30:00,666.7984,7.590645,1.324495
2015-05-26 14:40:00,911.0134,8.466603,1.708189  
2015-05-26 15:10:00,1256.1740,9.868224,1.636775  
2015-05-26 15:30:00,1706.7070,11.225540,1.576277"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
df
Out[113]:
                     ActivePowerkW  WindSpeedms  WindSpeedmsstd
time                                                           
2015-05-26 11:40:00       836.6328     8.234862        1.414558
2015-05-26 11:50:00       968.5992     8.761620        1.572579
2015-05-26 12:30:00       614.0503     7.267871        1.575504
2015-05-26 13:50:00       945.5604     8.709115        1.527079
2015-05-26 14:00:00       926.6531     8.538967        1.589221
2015-05-26 14:30:00       666.7984     7.590645        1.324495
2015-05-26 14:40:00       911.0134     8.466603        1.708189
2015-05-26 15:10:00      1256.1740     9.868224        1.636775
2015-05-26 15:30:00      1706.7070    11.225540        1.576277

In [115]:
# create your timeseries
timeseries_comp = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq='10min')
timeseries_comp
Out[115]:
DatetimeIndex(['2015-05-26 11:40:00', '2015-05-26 11:50:00',
               '2015-05-26 12:00:00', '2015-05-26 12:10:00',
               '2015-05-26 12:20:00', '2015-05-26 12:30:00',
               '2015-05-26 12:40:00', '2015-05-26 12:50:00',
               '2015-05-26 13:00:00', '2015-05-26 13:10:00',
               '2015-05-26 13:20:00', '2015-05-26 13:30:00',
               '2015-05-26 13:40:00', '2015-05-26 13:50:00',
               '2015-05-26 14:00:00', '2015-05-26 14:10:00',
               '2015-05-26 14:20:00', '2015-05-26 14:30:00',
               '2015-05-26 14:40:00', '2015-05-26 14:50:00',
               '2015-05-26 15:00:00', '2015-05-26 15:10:00',
               '2015-05-26 15:20:00', '2015-05-26 15:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='10T', tz=None)

In [120]:
# reindex
new_df = df.reindex(timeseries_comp)
# group on hour and minute, you can group on some other resolution
new_df.groupby([new_df.index.hour, new_df.index.minute]).apply(pd.Series.isnull).sum()
Out[120]:
ActivePowerkW     15
WindSpeedms       15
WindSpeedmsstd    15
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Would this count all NAN values for every month, hour or minute? It seems to count all null vales in the new_df

Comment: it depends on how you group it, in my answer I've used hour and minute but really you should also include year, month, day also so it can distinguish between different days. thinking about it maybe all you need is just `df.reindex(timeseries_comp).isnull().sum()`

Comment: I think I was not clear on what I'm after. I need to have the null/NAN values for every month (or in your example every hour). Not the total number of null values. I have edited my question and included a chart.

Comment: I think it that case do `new_df.groupby([new_df.index.year, new_df.index.month]).apply(pd.Series.isnull).sum()`